# How to resolve "no such table: " error in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

When i execute query i got this exception. please find the logcat.

please find the code here.

```
public static final String CLASS_ID="classid";
public static final String CLASS_NAME="classname";
public static final String TABLE_REMINDMEMASTER="remindmemaster";

public RemindmeDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, KonnectMeDataBase.DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
//create table remindmemaster table
String CREATE_REMINDME_MASTER="CREATE TABLE remindmemaster(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        +"instructions TEXT,rmd_f INTEGER,startdate TEXT,enddate TEXT,timings TEXT,"
        +" pid INTEGER,sync_f INTEGER,capturetime TEXT,serverid TEXT,crte_ts  TEXT , updt_ts TEXT)";
```

Logcat:

```
12-10 16:56:29.093: E/RemindMeDB(25575): remindmemaster Row Inserted at 
12-10 16:56:29.094: E/checkServeridExist(25575): serverid---0

12-10 16:56:29.094: E/checkServeridExist(25575): localServerId---null

12-10 16:56:29.095: E/SQLiteLog(25575): (1) no such table: remindmemaster

12-10 16:56:29.101: E/SQLiteDatabase(25575): Error inserting serverid= updt_ts=2014-12-10 16:56:29 rmd_f=0 startdate=10-12-2014 instructions=hiii capturetime=16:56:29 timings=16:24,16:25, pid=0 crte_ts=2014-12-10 16:56:29 enddate=30-12-2014 sync_f=0
12-10 16:56:29.101: E/SQLiteDatabase(25575): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: remindmemaster (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO remindmemaster(serverid,updt_ts,rmd_f,startdate,instructions,capturetime,timings,pid,crte_ts,enddate,sync_f) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
12-10 16:56:29.101: E/SQLiteDatabase(25575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-10 16:56:29.101: E/SQLiteDatabase(25575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)

12-10 16:56:29.101: E/SQLiteDatabase(25575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-10 16:56:29.101: 
E/SQLiteDatabase(25575):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
```

Comment: You are missing the code that calls the create table, and the code that trys to access it...

Make sure you create the table before trying to insert/get from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got answer, When mismatch database fields order and sending values to database fields order,  that time this type of error will  come.
When Raise this error please check these details.

1) check the order of database fields and sending method fields(inserting fields order).

2) Check this query is executed or not.

3) Check"onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)" for our query is registered or not in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Either you added this create table call after installing application in device once, or its not being created properly.

Add a space between table name and bracket:

```
String CREATE_REMINDME_MASTER="CREATE TABLE remindmemaster (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        +"instructions TEXT,rmd_f INTEGER,startdate TEXT,enddate TEXT,timings TEXT,"
        +" pid INTEGER,sync_f INTEGER,capturetime TEXT,serverid TEXT,crte_ts  TEXT , updt_ts TEXT)";
```

Plus, clear data, uninstall, then re run application and check. That should work.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: have you try to execute CREATE_REMINDME_MASTER statement ? which created table successfully might be clear data or uninstall may help.

Comment: Hi laalto, can you check check logcat once, and tell me what is the problem? When we will get this type errors.